# React Native push notification crash the application

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

I am setting up the push notification in Android, FCM generated but the application crashed when the notification received to the device and i also want to store the fcm token in the server

App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Text, Image} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification'

// import FormScreen from './form';
// import RegisterScreen from './register';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import NewScreen from './New';

const LoginScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [intialEmail, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [intialName, setName] = useState('');

  const userRegister = async () => {
    //alert('ok'); // version 0.48

    PushNotification.configure({

      // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
      onRegister: function(token) {
          console.log( 'TOKEN:', token );
      },
  
      // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
      onNotification: function(notification) {
          console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:', notification );
      },
  
      // ANDROID ONLY: (optional) GCM Sender ID.
      // senderID: "YOUR GCM SENDER ID",
  
      // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
      // permissions: {
      //     alert: true,
      //     badge: true,
      //     sound: true
      // },
  
      // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
      // default: true
      popInitialNotification: true,
  
      /**
        * (optional) default: true
        * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
        * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
        */
      // requestPermissions: true,
  });

    const username = intialEmail;
    const password = intialName;
    // I want to store the fcm token
    const newToken = ???;
    

    try {
      //await AsyncStorage.setItem('username', username);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('password', password);
    } catch (e) {
      // saving error
    }

    fetch('https://example.com/login.php', {
      method: 'post',
      header: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        //email: username,
        password: password,
      }),
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (responseJson == 'Login Successful') {
          //alert("Login Successful");
          navigation.navigate('New', {reference: password});
        } else {
          alert('Incorrect Login Details');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      // const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');
      const password = await AsyncStorage.getItem('password');
      // if (username !== null) {
        
      //   setEmail(username);
      // }
      if (password !== null) {
        // value previously stored
        setName(password);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // error reading value
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fe5900',
      }}>
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        {/*<Image style={{resizeMode: 'contain', width:200}} source={require('./assets/logo.png')} />*/}
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>
          Welcome to Smile
        </Text>
        <Image
          style={{width: 200, height: 100, resizeMode: 'contain'}}
          source={{
            uri: 'https://example.com/img/logo.png',
          }}
        />
       

        <TextInput
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            paddingLeft: 10,
            marginBottom: 10,
            width: 300,
            height: 50,
            color: 'grey',
          }}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          // secureTextEntry={true}
          placeholder="Enter your reference no"
          value={intialName}
          onChangeText={newName => setName(newName)}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            backgroundColor: '#333',
            marginTop: 15,
            textAlign: 'center',
            width: 150,
            paddingTop: 10,
            paddingBottom: 10,
            paddingLeft: 20,
            paddingRight: 20,
          }}
          onPress={userRegister}>
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: 'white'}}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            marginTop: 15,
            textAlign: 'center',
            width: 150,
            paddingTop: 10,
            paddingBottom: 10,
            paddingLeft: 20,
            paddingRight: 20,
          }}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Register')}>
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: 'white'}}>
            Forget Password
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {
        <Stack.Navigator initialRoutName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Star"
            component={LoginScreen}
            options={({navigation, route}) => ({
              title: 'Smile Shop',
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#333',
              },
              headerTintColor: '#fff',
              headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
              },
              //headerRight: () => (
              // <View style={{flex:1, height:25, flexDirection:'row', paddingRight:10, marginTop:10, marginBottom:10}}>
              // <View style={{marginRight:10}}>
              //   <Button
              //     onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
              //     title="Register"
              //     color="#020"
              //     height='30'
              //   />
              // </View>
              // <View>
              //   <Button
              //     onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
              //     title="Login"
              //     color="#020"
              //   />
              // </View>
              // </View>
              //),
            })}
          />
          {/* <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} /> */}
          {/* <Stack.Screen name="Product" component={ProductScreen} /> */}
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
          
          <Stack.Screen
            name="New"
            component={NewScreen}
            options={{
              title: 'Dashboard',
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#333',
              },
              headerTintColor: '#fff',
              headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
              },
            }}
          />
          
        </Stack.Navigator>
      }
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Android > Build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")

        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3')
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Android > app > build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.prosmile"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

MainApplicaion.java

```
package com.prosmile;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

import com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.ReactNativePushNotificationPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          //packages.add(new ReactNativePushNotificationPackage());
          
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.prosmile.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

settings.gradle file

```
rootProject.name = 'prosmile'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':react-native-push-notification'
project(':react-native-push-notification').projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android')

include ':app'
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "prosmile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.10.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.10.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.11.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "25.5.1",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "25.5.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

FCM token generated but the app getting crashed when the notification received.

Answer (score 1):

do you have any GSM - related lines in AndroidManifest.xml?
if yes, try removing them.

AndroidManifest.xml example:

```
<manifest ...>
    .....
    <application ...>
        .....
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>
        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        .....
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Source: [here](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/796)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure having `PushNotification.configure()` inside a component is what is breaking it, or at least part of it.